# Use date-fns to format day as UTC

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have the following date format `2022-07-20` and I would like to parse into the following format `2022-07-20T00:00:00.000Z`

I'm using the following code

```
const main = () => {
  const day = '2022-07-20'

  const date = new Date()
  const result = parse(day.toString(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', date)

  console.log(result.toISOString())
}
```

And getting the following output `2022-07-19T21:00:00.000Z`. I assume this happening because my timezone is UTC+3.
How do I get it formatted as `2022-07-20T00:00:00.000Z`?

Comment: What's the reason behind wanting this exact format?

Comment: `new Date('2022-07-20').toISOString()` will output `'2022-07-20T00:00:00.000Z'`

Comment: @CcmU that method doesn't provide the desired output.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#try_it)? It could be used to obtain the date with the desired timezone and use that like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127122/10301322)

Comment: I need to get Unix timestamp that starts at midnight of 20th of July